# Duplicate events while Importing calendar in Outlook

Tags: c#, vb.net, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm creating an ics file and each event has a unique UID as GuiD.NewGuid(). It is successfully imported first time. When there is a change in schedule I create updated ics file, It creates a duplicate while importing as it again creates a unique UID by calling GuiD.NewGuid(). Is there a way to avoid duplicates while importing.

```
writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")
     For i = 1 To 42
        lbl = Me.FindControl("Label" & i.ToString)
               If lbl.Text.IndexOf(str) > 0 Then
                    writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VEVENT")
                    sDateTime = CDate(GetStart().ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") & "Z"
                    eDateTime = CDate(GetEnd()).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") & "Z"
                    writer.WriteLine("DTSTART:" + sDateTime)
                    writer.WriteLine("DTEND:" + eDateTime)
                    writer.WriteLine("DTSTAMP:" + Now().ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") & "Z")
                    writer.WriteLine("UID:" & System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString.Replace("-", ""))
                    writer.WriteLine("END:VEVENT")
               End If
    Next
                   writer.WriteLine("END:VCALENDAR")
                   writer.Close()
```

Comment: Could you post the code you've used so far?  It will put us all in the context of where we could eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: I have posted relevent code. It creates a UID  whnever it comes across an event. But it will generate a unique one everytime I create an ics file and hence create duplicates while importing into Outlook.

Comment: For this situation, can you isolate the event's by their start/end time and or description?  It may require a separate table where you record those, log the guid, and then you could pull that info say if you need to have it overwrite the original or skip the duplicate.

Comment: you said 'import' not 'subscribe'.  In my view the two are different.  I would expect a 'subscribe' to match the UID's and not create duplicates.  An 'import' well I tend to think of that as being more like it would be treated as though I created the events myself.  'Imported' events are imported into the base calendar, not subscribed as a separate calendar.  Frankly it wouldn't surprise me if duplicates were created on an import.